# Flutter responsive gridView

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a responsive design using grid view in my Flutter project, but I'm getting this overflow error, how can I fix it?

```dart
Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  child: GridView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: avatarList.length,
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount:
                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.shortestSide < 600
                                ? 2
                                : 4,
                        // mainAxisSpacing: 20,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                        childAspectRatio: 1),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Avatars(
                          ID: avatarList[index][0],
                          avatarPath: avatarList[index][1],
                          avatarName: avatarList[index][2],
                          isOwned: avatarList[index][3]);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

my code is like this

avatar.dart  like this:

```dart
class Avatars extends StatelessWidget {
      final int ID;
      final String avatarPath;
      final String avatarName;
      bool isOwned;
    
      Avatars({
        super.key,
        required this.ID,
        required this.avatarPath,
        required this.avatarName,
        required this.isOwned,
      });
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (isOwned) {
      ownedColor = lightGreen;
    } else if (!isOwned) {
      ownedColor = navyBlue;
    }

    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              boxShadow: [MyBoxShadow(navyBlue)]),
          child: Image(
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            image: AssetImage(avatarPath),
          ),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 5),
        Text(
          avatarName,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: ownedColor),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

avatars.dart like this ı try gridview builder and avatarList.lenght but didn't

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you share Avatars code?

Comment: updated avatars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `gridDelegate` as `SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent` instead. Here you just need to define the width and height and the widget for the `GridView` will get adjusted accordingly.

```
GridView.builder(
                    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: companyModuleProvider.companies.length,
                    gridDelegate:
                        const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                      mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                      maxCrossAxisExtent: 200, //your width
                      mainAxisExtent: 100, //your height
                    ),
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                         Avatars(
                          ID: avatarList[index][0],
                          avatarPath: avatarList[index][1],
                          avatarName: avatarList[index][2],
                          isOwned: avatarList[index][3],
                          ),
                        ),
```

Give it a try.